# how to check if item in a list is exist in other list with python?

Tags: python

I have a text file containing these lines for example

```
[:];@;;]wqwww actualnumber 1234 ;;:@##
aaaa ''3# allnumber 9876
///qqq |||)))
]][]: best 56
```

I want to get the value `1234`,`9876`,`56`. Like this(desired output)

```
1234
9876
56
```

I tried with the following script but it did not print out anything

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

    word = ["actual number", "potential", "time"]
    if any(item in stripped_lines for item in word):
        aa = stripped_lines.split("actualnumber ")[1].split(" ")[0]
        bb = stripped_lines.split("allnumber ")[1].split(" ")[1]
        cc = stripped_lines.split("best ")[1]

        print aa
        print bb
        print cc
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you actually want to search numbers by keywords in a string, or you just want to grab any number in a string?

Comment: I actually want to grab the number in specific position. Hence why I want `9876` not `3`. If you can see in the text file, basically I want to get the number after a certain keyword

Comment: Hi @Ling may be it will help to find out same values,
match_values = [i for item in stripped_lines for i in word if item in i]
for value in match_values:
 print(value)

Comment: @Ling I have edited my answer. Assuming that number always comes right after the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with re module

```
import re
with open('f.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    act = re.findall(r'actualnumber\s+(\d+)',data)
    best = re.findall(r'best\s(\d+)',data)
    allnumber = re.findall(r'allnumber\s(\d+)',data)
    print "actualnumber  : ", act[0] if act else None
    print "allnumber  : ", allnumber[0] if allnumber else None
    print "best  : ", best[0] if best else None
```

output

```
actualnumber  :  1234
allnumber  :  9876
best  :  56
```

Comment: this is great but I want to get for each value not as list. I mean, for example `aa` will print `1234`, `bb` will print `9876` and `cc` will print `56`. So that I can use value of `aa` that is `1234` on other operation

Comment: @Ling Do you have to store them in variables aa, bb, cc? Or would a dictionary be suitable? For example ``{ 'allnumber' : 9876 }``.

Comment: I want to store those value in database, that is why I want to get them in variables.

Comment: r u ok with this output ? @Ling :)

Comment: yes, this is what i want to do. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can extract numbers like this:

```
k = '[:];@;;]wqwww actualnumber 1234 ;;:@##'
for item in k.split():
    if item.isnumeric():
        print(item)
```

You would use your striped lines instead. For each line in stripped line, split it, and check if any item in the split line is numeric. `isnumeric()` works only on unicode objects.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

words = ['actualnumber', 'allnumber', 'best']
found = {}
for line in stripped_lines:
    current_line = line.split()
    for position, item in enumerate(current_line):
        if item in words:
            found[item] = current_line[position + 1]
```

Now that you have them in a dictionary, you can access them as: `found['actualnumber']`. And do further processing, such as storing them in a database.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is by using `isdigit()`

```
f = open('test.txt')
data = f.read()
[int(s) for s in data.split() if s.lstrip("-").isdigit()]
```

Output :

```
[1234, 9876, 56]
```

Comment: What if digits is negative? ``"-1".isdigit()`` returns ``False``.

Comment: @Liliane You can use lsstrip("-") in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
    word = ["actualnumber", "potential", "time"]
    with open("./abx.txt") as file:
         temp_list = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
         list_val = [item for item in temp_list if any(x in item for x in word)]
         final_list = []
         match_value = ["actualnumber", "allnumber", "best"]
         if list_val:
           for val in temp_list:
             val_list = val.split(" ")
             for key, value in enumerate(val_list):
                 if value in match_value:
                    final_list.append(val_list[key+1])

        print(final_list):
```

And at the end you can iterate list and find out your expected values.